# enviar correo al momento de guardar con ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

Tengo un sistema de ventas, en donde quiero enviar un correo cada que se haga un pedido ya he intentado vairos metodos, incluso intente con PHPMailer, quiero que al mismo tiempo que se guarda la info en la base, se envie un correo a la persona quien esta subiendo dicho pedido.

lo tengo de la siguente manera;

```
archivo 1 Modelo
    require "../config/Conexion.php";
    Class Pedido{
    public function __construct()
    {
    }
    public function 
InsertarPedido($usuario,$quien_solicita,$folio,$cliente,$cliente_destino,$direccion,$contacto,$telefono,$correo,$tipo_envio,$solicitud_envio,$fecha_tenvio,$fecha_pedido,$pedido_pendiente,$observaciones,$autorizacion_envio,$id_pedido,$modelo,$color,$sku,$cantidad)
    {
$sql="INSERT INTO pedido (usuario,quien_solicita,folio,cliente,cliente_destino,direccion,contacto,telefono,correo,tipo_envio,solicitud_envio,fecha_tenvio,fecha_pedido,pedido_pendiente,observaciones,estatus_gnral,autorizacion_envio)VALUES ('$usuario','$quien_solicita','$folio','$cliente','$cliente_destino','$direccion','$contacto','$telefono','$correo','$tipo_envio','$solicitud_envio','$fecha_tenvio','$fecha_pedido','$pedido_pendiente','$observaciones','Aceptado','$autorizacion_envio')";       
        $idpedidonew=ejecutarConsulta_retornarID($sql);
        $num_elementos=0;
        $sw=true;
        while ($num_elementos < count($modelo))
      {
$sql_detalle = "INSERT INTO detalle_pedido (id_pedido,modelo,color,sku,cantidad) VALUES('$idpedidonew','$modelo[$num_elementos]','$color[$num_elementos]','$sku[$num_elementos]','$cantidad[$num_elementos]')";
          ejecutarConsulta($sql_detalle) or $sw = false;
          $num_elementos=$num_elementos + 1;
      }
      return $sw;
    }
}

Archivo 2: Ajax
require_once "Modelo.php";
(Aqui coloco todas las variables que ocupo para esa funcion)
switch ($_GET["op"]){
case 'InsertarPedido':
$pedido= new Pedido();
$rspta=$pedido->InsertarPedido($usuario,$quien_solicita,$folio,$cliente,$cliente_destino,$direccion,$contacto,$telefono,$correo,$tipo_envio,$solicitud_envio,$fecha_tenvio,$fecha_pedido,$pedido_pendiente,$observaciones,$autorizacion_envio,$_POST["id_pedido"],$_POST["modelo"],$_POST["color"],$_POST["sku"],$_POST["cantidad"]);
echo $rspta ? "Ingreso registrado, folio de pedido ".$folio : "No se pudieron registrar todos los datos del ingreso";
    break;
}

Archivo2: script
function InsertarPedido(e)
{
    e.preventDefault();
    $("#btnGuardar").prop("disabled",false);
    var formData = new FormData($("#formulario")[0]);
    $.ajax({
        url: "../ajax/AjaxMovimientos.php?op=InsertarPedido",
        type: "POST",
        data: formData,
        contentType: false,
        processData: false,
        success: function(datos)
        {                    
        alert(datos);
        TablaSalidas.ajax.reload();
        }
    });
}

el asunto es que ya intente poner la funcion en el archivo ajax de la siguente manera

$asunto="Se ingreso un pedido con el folio ".$folio;
$header="No contestar el correo";
$mensaje="pedido ingresado por".$quien_solicita;
$email=mail($destinatario,$asunto,$mensaje);
case 'InsertarPedido':
$pedido= new Pedido();
$rspta=$pedido->InsertarPedido($usuario,$quien_solicita,$folio,$cliente,$cliente_destino,$direccion,$contacto,$telefono,$correo,$tipo_envio,$solicitud_envio,$fecha_tenvio,$fecha_pedido,$pedido_pendiente,$observaciones,$autorizacion_envio,$_POST["id_pedido"],$_POST["modelo"],$_POST["color"],$_POST["sku"],$_POST["cantidad"],$email);
        echo $rspta ? "Ingreso registrado, folio de pedido ".$folio : "No se pudieron registrar todos los datos del ingreso";
    break;
}
```

tambien intente hacer una funcion desde el archivo de las clase, igual un arhcivo independiente con un action desde el formulario y no obtengo el resultado.

me da el siguente error

```
<b>Warning</b>:  mail(): Failed to connect to mailserver at &quot;tls://smtp.gmail.com&quot; port 587, verify your &quot;SMTP&quot; and &quot;smtp_port&quot; setting in php.ini or use ini_set() in <b>C:\xampp\htdocs\sistema_garantias_1\SGTv2.6\ajax\AjaxMovimientos.php</b> on line <b>59</b><br />
{"sEcho":1,"iTotalRecords":0,"iTotalDisplayRecords":0,"aaData":[]}
```

espero me puedan ayudar.

Comment: Mi primera observación es que no estás usando consultas preparadas, lo cual te expone a ataques por [inyección SQL](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inyecci%C3%B3n_SQL)

Comment: Parece que el servidor, o la.maquina e  la que ejecura la plicacion no tiene acceso a la IP donde está el servicio de correo SMTP

Comment: Si cuento con la seguridad para insersion de codigo mal intencionado, no lo coloque porque no es relevante para mi pregunta, la duda es como hago la funcion para envio de correo al mismo tiempo en que se guarde en la base la informacion. ya he intentado varias cosas y nada me funciona.

Answer (score 0):

Deberías verificar la configuración del servidor **SMTP** que hasta donde tengo entendido **Gmail** cancelo ese tipo de conexiones, tal vez me equivoque pero revisa al respecto, si sigue funcionando debes darle permiso a la cuenta de correo para que puedas conectarte por **SMTP** de lo contrario Gmail no te permitirá.

Por último si estás trabajando local revisa que tengas bien configurado el php.ini para enviar correos.

Deberías leer este artículo:
https://kinsta.com/es/blog/gmail-smtp-servidor/

Comment: Esto no responde la pregunta. Te invito a leer [answer]. Para comentarios puedes usar el área destinada a comentarios. Un enlace no es una respuesta. Saludos